# Can a Custom Spinner items have vertical scroll in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner with custom adapter and layout. The spinner items can have a very long text. So, can I use maxlines in textview and make the textview scrollable. Is there any way?

Comment: i suggest you to use listView to support long text length

Comment: easiest way to show whole text is`Auto Horizontal Marquee`